# Text to speech unusual behaviour in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am having a strange experience with text to speech.

see my code:

```
Button b;
TextView title, body;
TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popups);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonok);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
    body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewbody);
    b.setText("ok");
    title.setText(Receive.address);
    body.setText(Receive.body);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(Popup.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        }
    });
            play();//this is not working??!!i don't know why
    b.performClick();//even this is not working
            /* but when i click this button it works??? how and why?*/
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            play(); // Popup.this.finish();
        }
    });
}

private void play() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tts.speak(Receive.body, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
```

My text to speech works fine only when i click the button but whenever i don't click this button and write the tts.speak() inside normal code it do not works...why?

regards  charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for `onInit` being called before you can start `speak`. In your code you call play() right after the declaration. onInit is a callback and it takes some time before it being called. If you click your button as soon as the button appears, sometime it will fail as onInit has not been called. You should have a class member `boolean mIsReady` and set it to true in **onInit**. And in your `play()` method

```
private void play() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (mIsReady) {
tts.speak(Receive.body, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! I have been stuck on this issue for days!

Answer (score 2):

```
b.performClick();//even this is not working
        /* but when i click this button it works??? how and why?*/
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        play(); // Popup.this.finish();
    }
});
```

You are performing a click with `b.performClick()` before setting its `setOnClickListener`. Also, you are better off making such calls on the `onResume()` method. OnCreate is meant to be used to bind views and prepare the activity. The `onResume()` method will be called before showing the view to the user on the foreground so that would be the best place to put this code.

Take a look at the activity lifecycle.

[image: activity]